# Ubuntu stuck on boot with multiple GPUs and onboard graphics

Tags: ubuntu, boot, graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

I installed ubuntu 16.04. I have a mining rig that has 6 MSI RX470 4 gb with Asrock Pro BTC motherboard.

I've set the graphics chipset to onboard before and installed ubuntu through it. Than I installed the latest AMD drivers from the website. It asked me to reboot.

When I try to reboot it gets stuck on recovering journal.

I tried literally every solution I could find, including nomodeset and fresh installs (been working for 14 hours straight now) and nothing seems to solve my problem.

I than switched the motherboard gpu chipset to PCI-E and was able to boot but with only 1 GPU. As soon as I shutdown and plug the second second GPU in, motherboard doesn't recognize the GPU with monitor plugged in.

I would really like to know what I must do to boot using onboard graphics card while having my 6 GPUs active.

Any help is more than welcome.